# How Can I see steps of running codes in phpstorm?

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

I have a problem in my PHP codes I cant find that. because dont display any warning or error and redirect to the main page of my website project and after many test couldnt find problem.

I want to see steps of running the code for example:

get values of $click and $usercode variables===> redirect to request_change.php and run mysql_query with value="select * from users where userid=65643"==> get $username ==> and else...

I can see some running steps by debugging but not exact that I Want and display many error about finding some directories in require_once function but while my webpages display and process information right by wamp.

Is any way to debugging same as that by Phpstorm or any other programs?

OR
 How can I run My php code in phpstorm step-by-step and line-by-line??

#### Update:

I configured phpstorm for debugging but Just I can use debug and select one of page to debug.**I checked all the settings steps that were done correctly But The step by step debug buttons is'nt active such as stepOver and step intro and else...** In addition, after debugging the codes, the error :   *PHP Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '.\dref.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\srn\mrt\req_v.php on line 260*
  is displayed, while the same code works well in the wamp by Firefox

**What should I do to solve this problem?**

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

One of the most powerful and useful tools any developer could have is a debugger. I use xDebug myself. With it you can step through a program during execution and watch each method call, every variable value change, and every action the program does. With PHPStorm it is typically very easy to enable / use xDebug. This would be my recommendation for troubleshooting the issue you have.

References:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide

Comment: Thanks.I configure it but Just I can use debug and select one of page to debug.I check all steps to do right. **The step by step debug buttons isnt active such as stepOver and step intro and else...**  In addition, after debugging the codes, the error : _PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '.\dref.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\srn\mrt\req_v.php on line 260_  is displayed, while the same code works well in the wamp by Firefox